# Binary Search Tree, walking through the list with an object

Tags: java

I have an issue walking through my tree and checking all of the items to see if the tree contains that item. I have to do it with an Object... Is there anybody who can help?

```
testSet.clear( );
    testSet.add( 10);
    testSet.add( 20);
    testSet.add( 30);
    testSet.add( 40);
    testSet.add( 15);
    testSet.add( 25);
    testSet.add( 5);
    testSet.add( 1);
    assertFalse("contains must return false for the element 80", testSet.contains(80));
    assertFalse("contains must return false for the element 3", testSet.contains(3));
    assertTrue("contains must return true for the element 10", testSet.contains(10));
    assertTrue("contains must return true for the element 5", testSet.contains(5));
    assertTrue("contains must return true for the element 1", testSet.contains(1));
    assertTrue("contains must return true for the element 20", testSet.contains(20));
    assertTrue("contains must return true for the element 25", testSet.contains(25));
    assertTrue("contains must return true for the element 40", testSet.contains(40));       
    testSet.clear( );
    assertFalse("contains must return false for any element after a clear", testSet.contains(10));
```

I am getting the error:
assertTrue("contains must return true for the element 20", testSet.contains(20));

```
public boolean contains(Object o) 
{
    if (o == null)
    {
        throw new NullPointerException("Null Items are not allowed in the Tree");
    }
    Node cur = root;
    for(int i =0; i <size -1; i++)
    {
    if(cur.item.equals(o))
            {

                return true;
            }
            if(!cur.item.equals(o))
            {
            cur=cur.lChild; 

                if (cur.item.equals(o))
                {
                return true;
                }
                if (!cur.item.equals(o))
                {
                    cur=cur.lChild;
                }
                if (cur.item.equals(o))
                {
                    return true;
                }
                else
                {
                    return false;
                }

            }


        else{
                cur = cur.rChild;
                if(cur.item.equals(o))
                {
                    return true;
                }
                if (!cur.item.equals(o))
                {
                    cur=cur.rChild;
                    if (cur.item.equals(o))
                    {
                        return true;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        return false;
                    }
                }
        }




        }
    return true;
}

}
```

Comment: Can you post the whole BinaryTree class?

Comment: Next time when you ask a question, spend 1 second [format the code](http://codebeautify.org/javaviewer) first. It is a bit hard to read.

Answer (score 1):

First, you need to determine if `cur` is smaller than or larger than `o` when `cur` don't equal to `o`. Which means you can't use `Object`, instead you need to use [`Comparable`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Comparable.html). The function `compareTo(T anotherObject)` tells you wherever the object is smaller, larger or equal to `anotherObject`. When `cur` is less than `o`, you need to go left, else go right.

Also, you need to search it recursively, which means when you go down, you need to call the function itself like `contains(cur.lChild)` or `contains(cur.rChild)`.

Your `contains` function should like this:

```
public boolean contains(Comparable o) {
    if (o == null) {
        throw new NullPointerException("Null Items are not allowed in the Tree");
    }
    Node cur = this;
    for (int i = 0; i < size - 1; i++) {
        if (cur.item.compareTo(o) == 0) {
            return true;
        } else if (cur.item.compareTo(o) < 0) {
            cur = cur.lChild;
        } else {
            cur = cur.rChild;
        }
        return cur.contains(o);
    }
    return true;
}
```